# how to call my Java Script function correctly?

Tags: javascript

i just started learning JS i cant find what is wrong with my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        myfunc(){
            var no1=parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
            var no2=parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
            document.getElementById("f").innerHTML=no1+no2;
            }
        </script>
        num1: <input type="text" id="n1"/>+num2: <input type="text" id="n2"/>
        <button onclick="myfunc()">=</button>
        <p id="f"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the function keyword else you will get error that myfunc() is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare your function using the *function* reserved word

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function myfunc(){
            var no1=parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
            var no2=parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
            document.getElementById("f").innerHTML=no1+no2;
            }
        </script>
        num1: <input type="text" id="n1"/>+num2: <input type="text" id="n2"/>
        <button onclick="myfunc()">=</button>
        <p id="f"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function myfunc(){
            var no1=parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
            var no2=parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
            document.getElementById("f").innerHTML=no1+no2;
            }
        </script>
        num1: <input type="text" id="n1"/>+num2: <input type="text" id="n2"/>
        <button onclick="myfunc()">=</button>
        <p id="f"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hey there! You need to use the word function before myfunc() to define this function.